# how can i include backend REST api in my app

Tags: android, android-studio

I've downloaded a phone-book app from git hub and in the description it asked me to add back end REST API. I've also downloaded the folder of API  but don't know how to add and use it in my project. can anybody please cooperate.

Comment: itis totally unclear why the phonebook app needs some backend, what kind of backend is it, and how should it be included, as well as where it should be included. You better ask in that repository on github

Comment: ok thanks . i'll ask there ..

Comment: If you want to learn how to call REST api from android app you need to learn AsyncTask, Volley or Retrofit.